# Is it only resolution that matters in Responsive Web Design

Tags: css

I am new to Responsive Web Design and I am trying to understand...Suppose the following css:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 680px) {
...
}
```

Is it yes or no the above rules will be applied only to resolutions less than 680px? If it is yes, then a smart phone with 900px screen width and a 4 inches size will not be affected. 
From the other hand, I know the above phone must be affected since its screen is very small. What am I missing? Do the above rules apply to the smart phone or not and what is the logic?
Thank you very much

Comment: it's about screen density

Comment: it's not resolution, it's pixel density

Comment: I 'd appreciate a more detailed explanation. 680px is density? How do we measure screen density?

Comment: max-width has nothing to do with resolution, but the width of the viewport.  You're thinking of max-device-width.